# Using aws s3 and cloudfront to host React application.Can anyone suggest configuration to access dynamic urls?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

For e.g. website url is https://www.myreactapp.com. It has some other pages with dynamic get parameters.

https://www.myreactapp.com/category/1

https://www.myreactapp.com/category/2

It's giving me Access Denied error

Comment: Does your S3 bucket have public access granted in its bucket policy or use a origin access identity?

Comment: Yes, bucket has public access

Comment: In which case this will be object does not exist. Can you access the S3 path on that matching path? How does the origin configuration look?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine by accessing s3 bucket path, but not working using cloudfront url

Comment: If you can put CloudFront origin I'll take a look. Out of curiosity does it work by putting the real key path (assuming `https://www.myreactapp.com/category/2` is `https://www.myreactapp.com/category/2/index.html`)?

Comment: I have changed my origin type from s3 to custom in cloudfront configuration, then it started working. Thanks a lot Chris

Comment: Hmm that’s odd, does it work as expected with custom origin for you?

Comment: Yea, It's working with custom origin name.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue where i'm trying to access content at run time using ajax.

Set S3 bucket Access as "Objects can be public", No need to set "Public" Access for Static website hosting.

Use **S3 Origin** if you want CloudFront to deliver any objects that place in S3 bucket. But if you generate run time content, its batter to use **Custom Origin**.

For **Custom Origin** keep Note: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the OP was to update the origin from S3 to Custom Origin domain. This allowed expected behaviour to work.

Validated that bucket was public, error 403 was caused by key not existing.